# Fail a keyword without stopping the test execution in robotframework

Tags: robotframework

The way i raise errors from my keywords is by using the robot.api.logger class

```
def test_keyword():
    logger.error("Report error")
```

This creates an error line in the log.html file under the keyword but does not fail the keyword.

The way i fail a keyword is by raising exceptions.

```
def test_keyword():
    raise Exception("Not implemented")
```

This fails the keyword as well as the test case in which the keyword was called. But this also stops the further execution of the test case.

Is there any way i can fail a keyword without stopping the test case execution?

Comment: What is the sense of it? Keyword fails - test case fails. What is the reason of continuing the test execution?

Comment: Can you explain in what way this would differ from your current `logger.error()` approach? From your description it seems that this does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Psytho : Consider a Test case with multiple verify/validate keywords within a test case. eg: `verify_xyz_component_is_visible()`, `verify_total_displayed_for_column()` etc. If my first keyword `verify_xyz_component_is_visible()` fails, i still would like to check the status of my second keyword `verify_total_displayed_for_column()` and keywords after that before stopping the execution of my test

Comment: You can use ``Run Keyword And Ignore Error`` or ``Run Keyword And Continue On Failure`` or ``Run Keyword And Return Status``.

Comment: @A.Kootstra : Calling `logger.error()` from within a keyword logs the error but the status of that keyword is still `PASS`. What i want is to have a mechanism by which i can fail a keyword(change the status to `FAIL` without stopping the execution

Comment: @Psytho : Thank you for your response! Is there a 'pythonic' way of doing this

Comment: I don't think there is a pythonic way in Robot Framework for anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#continue-on-failure):

Library keywords report failures using exceptions, and it is possible to use special exceptions to tell the core framework that execution can continue regardless the failure.

When a test ends and there has been one or more continuable failure, the test will be marked failed. If there are more than one failure, all of them will be enumerated in the final error message:

```
Several failures occurred:

1) First error message.

2) Second error message ...
```

The way to signal this from test libraries is adding a special ROBOT_CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE attribute with True value to the exception used to communicate the failure. This is demonstrated by the examples below.

```
class MyContinuableError(RuntimeError):
    ROBOT_CONTINUE_ON_FAILURE = True
```